# Php variable accessed from class in another file empty

Tags: php, apache, backend

I am new to php and I am trying to program an app that uses php as backend. I don't really have an error in my code but I can't figure something out I have search but nothing has helped.there maybe be a solution but I can't find it.
I have 3 php file

`Index.php`

```
<?php 
include "methods.php";
$user=new user();
if (isset($_GET["action"])) {
  // code...
  switch ($_GET["action"]) {
    case 'login':
      // code...
      $user->login();
      break;
    default:
      // code...
      echo("error 404");
      break;
  }

} else {
  // code...
  echo("error 404");
}

?>
```

`Methods.php`

```
<?php
include "extra.php";
class user {
  public function login() {
    $input = new input();
    $error = "fucked";
    $validationresult = json_decode($input->validateinput(), true);
    echo var_dump($validationresult);
    $validated = $validationresult["validated"];
    if ($validated) {
      // code...
      echo ("yes");

    } else {
      echo var_dump($validationresult);
    //  echo json_encode(($validationresult["error"]));
    }
  }
}
?>
```

`extra.php`

```
<?php
class input {
  public $password;
  public $status;
  public $validated;
  public function __construct()
  {
    // code...
  }
  public function validateinput () {
    $password = $_GET["password"];
   $this-> $status = "red";
    $this->$validated = false;
    echo($this-> $status);
    return json_encode('{
    "validated":'.$this->get_validate().',
    "error":{
    "status":"'.$this->$status.'",
     "username":"ok",
     "password":"cannot be more than 5"
    }
  }');

  }
public function get_validate(){
return $this->$validated;
}
}
?>
```

As you can see in `index.php` I called `$user->login();`
From `methods.php` which echos JSON `$input->validateinput()` from file `extra.php`.
But

```
"validated":'.$this->get_validate().'
```

And

```
"status":"'.$this->$status.'
```

From `extra.php`
Is empty
I don't why it is empty and the internet confuses me more.
I am sorry for my grammatical mistakes as I am typing from a mobile phone and English isn't my first language.

Comment: I immediately notice two things. 1: When accessing class properties, do not use a dollar sign. So use `$this->status` instead of `$this->$status`. 2: You're passing an already json-encoded string to `json_encode()`. This will double-encode it. You should pass an array to `json_encode()` instead.